# How to create directory with the pc current date time format?

Tags: c#

```
private void CreateDir(string Folder)
{
    // Sample on Sun 01.12.2014 At 09.13 AM
    string locationToCreateFolder = Folder;
    string folderName = "";
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MM.dd.yyyy");
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm tt");
    string format = "{0} on {1} At {2}";
    folderName = string.Format(format, date, time);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(locationToCreateFolder + folderName);
}
```

This gives me exception on the line :

```
folderName = string.Format(format, date, time);
```

The line was in original :

```
folderName = string.Format(format, textBox1.Text, date, time);
```

but I don't have textBox1 control.

> System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
> at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
> at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1)

Comment: `date` is formatted in `{0}`, `time` is formatted in `{1}`... what did you want in `{2}` ? You don't provide a 4th parameter. (Or more likely, based on the text in `format`, you didn't provide what you wanted in `{0}` before `date`.)

Comment: By the way, your title has nothing to do with the problem you're encountering. You're getting a `FormatException` before you get to the point of creating the folder. The problem is about building a string. You need to write a better title.

Answer (score 4):

bad format string

```
string format = "{0} on {1} At {2}"; <<<== 3 args
folderName = string.Format(format, date, time); <<<<=== 2 supplied
```

you need

```
string format = "made on {0} At {1}";
folderName = string.Format(format, date, time);
```

or even

```
folderName = $"made on {date} at {time}";
```